# Does Lowenheim-Skolem theorem depend on axiom of choice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axiom-of-choice

The proofs of Lowenheim-Skolem I have seen all depended on the use of choice functions. Is there any proof not dependent on axiom of choice? Or is Lowenheim-Skolem a result of axiom of choice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Skolem-Lowenheim theorem is equivalent to $\sf DC$, which is a strong countable choice principle.

More generally, the following is true:

> Every structure has an elementary equivalent substructure of size $\leq\kappa$, if and only if $\sf DC+AC_\kappa$.

You can find the proof [here](http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Lowenheim-Skolem-and-Choice.pdf). In a nutshell, the idea is that given a family of sets, an elementary substructure which is well-orderable gives you a way to define a choice function. The other direction is the usual proof of Skolem-Lowenheim.

Comment: Thanks, for anyone that wants it in the future: http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Lowenheim-Skolem-and-Choice.pdf

Comment: I've updated the links (there were 4 links I've missed, so editing out didn't seem like the worst idea). Thanks for catching that!