# Version of Löwenheim-Skolem theorem and the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, axiom-of-choice

I was looking through *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* by Smullyan and Fitting and came across this note in Exercise 1.2 in Chapter 11 (pg 147 of Dover version).

> (We remark that the Skolem-Löwenheim theorem can be proved without the axiom of choice.)

However, it appears to be the case that the theorem is equivalent to the axiom of dependent choice. See, for instance, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1367393/397125). The statement in the book would be true in the sense that the full-strength axiom of choice is not required, but since this is an axiomatic set theory book, a statement like this seems like it would imply it's provable under ZF.

I'm wondering if this is just an oversight, or is it that they are using a weak version of the theorem that doesn't require any choice axiom? Their version of the theorem is given toward the end of section $0$ in the same chapter (p. 144):

> Given any denumerable set $S$ of pure formulas (i.e. w/o constants), if there is a relational system in which all the formulas of $S$ are satisfiable, then there is a denumerable such relational system.

Comment: I love this book (Cowen's theorem!) but unfortunately it is plagued with oversights and typos (which were not amended in the 2010 reprint).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Yeah, it's the first book on this stuff that's 'grabbed' me but it's exasperating. There's an errata but I'm in the middle of a 100-page gulf. Like the proof of chap 10 thm 2.7 seems to require transitivity. The paragraph above had a transitivity assumption inserted in the corrected edition, but the theorem's proof seems to refer to it like nothing happened. Why didn't they correct that too? And I'm left here wondering if the theorem actually requires transitivity, and it probably does, but the counterexample would have to be a proper class, and ugh.

Comment: Are you talking about Stephen Pollard's [review](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1039700750) of the 1996 edition of the book, or perhaps another existing errata? (the first option would immediately justify your "borrowed" use of the word "exasperating")  I would be interested in that (other) one!

Comment: No, never seen that before. I'm disappointed my ch 10 issue isn't in there cause it looks like he caught quite a few things that went uncorrected in the dover. (I'm also loving this diatribe on not defining equality in ch 11, was my thoughts exactly yesterday.) I think 'exasperating' would be pretty much anyone's take (although I also agree w/ 'rewarding'). This is the one I was talking about http://melvinfitting.org/errata/book_errors/RevisedSetBookErrors/RevisedSetCorrections.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This version indeed does not require the axiom of choice.  The more usual formulation that is equivalent to DC requires that the countable model you obtain be an *elementary submodel* of your original model.  The version you quoted can be proved without choice as follows.  First, if $S$ has a model, then it is consistent.  Henkin's proof of the completeness theorem (which does not require choice if your language is countable) then produces a countable model of $S$.