# How to make this proof (?) (with AC) of $|X\times X| = |X|$ for infinite $X$ rigorous.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

First of all, I do not want to make the statement that the following proof has any interest on its own: it's probably horrendous, in the sense that it's completely overkill, if a proof at all. It's only that I think it may be interesting for a better understanding of FOL and Set Theory to make it rigorous. The idea is the following:

First we prove that PA proofs that $f(x,y) := \frac{1}{2}(x+y)(x+y+1) + x$ is a bijection, in the sense that it proofs $\forall n(!\exists x,y(\frac{1}{2}(x+y)(x+y+1) + x = n))$. Then we argue by the upward Löwenheim–Skolem theorem that, since PA has a countable model, it has a model of every infinite cardinal, and thus, it must be that $|X \times X| = |X|$ for all infinite $X$.

I'm pretty sure there are many things to make precise. For example, I'm pretty sure one has to appeal to the soundness theorem at some point. These would be the things I would like to understand better. Anyway I hope this isn't too nonsensical.

Comment: This is a neat way of coming to the result, and one I haven’t seen before. In fact, it seems one could make it even simpler: consider the vocabulary with one binary function $f$ and the axiom $\forall x \exists y \exists z (f(y, z) = x \land \forall y’ \forall z’ (f(y’, z’) = x \to y = y’ \land z = z’))$. One concern is that the proof of the Lowenheim-Skolem theorems will probably rely on the very property that you’re trying to prove here, so you might have a circular argument.

Comment: It is probably circular in the sense that Mark describes, but the plus side is it is a nice proof that the Lowenheim Skolem theorem implies $\forall X\;|X\times X|=|X|$, and hence is equivalent to AC by Tarski’s theorem.

Comment: I thought it may be circular, but it made me curious anyway. As an exercise more than anything.

Comment: This argument (as a proof that (an appropriately stated version of) Löwenheim-Skolem is equivalent to AC) is actually reasonably well-known.  (Or at least, I've seen it elsewhere a few different places before.)

Comment: See [the relevant question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367342/does-lowenheim-skolem-theorem-depend-on-axiom-of-choice)